# why "middle = arr[(beg + end) / 2]" goes wrong?

Tags: c

I was implementing `quick_select` in c, but my code went wrong and it took me a very long time to find out why,but I still cannot understand.

The function `get_pivot` is to find a pivot for `quick_select`,here is the wrong code:

```
int get_pivot(int*arr, int beg, int end)
{

    int middle = arr[(beg + end) / 2];                    
    if (middle < arr[beg])
      swap(&middle, &arr[beg]);
    if (arr[end] < arr[beg])
      swap(&arr[beg], &arr[end]);
    if (middle>arr[end])
      swap(&middle, &arr[end]);
    swap(&middle, &arr[end - 1]);
    return arr[end - 1];
}
```

This function is designed to find out the middle number of 3 and move pivot to the end.

However,it went wrong (I mean the `quick_select` output unsorted array)until I replaced `int middle = arr[(beg + end) / 2];`with
`int middle=(beg+end)/2` and use `arr[middle]` instead of `middle`.Here is the right code:

```
int get_pivot(int*arr, int beg, int end)
{

    int middle = (beg + end) / 2;                  
    if (arr[middle] < arr[beg])
        swap(&arr[middle], &arr[beg]);
    if (arr[end] < arr[beg])
        swap(&arr[beg], &arr[end]);
    if (arr[middle]>arr[end])
        swap(&arr[middle], &arr[end]);
    //hide pivot
    swap(&arr[middle], &arr[end - 1]);

    return arr[end - 1];
}
```

I don't understand why `int middle = arr[(beg + end) / 2];`goes wrong.

I really appreciate you help!

Comment: It would be more obvious what went wrong if your array contained something not-at-all convertible to `int`. The former code wouldn't *compile* if that were the case, while the latte would stand a fighting chance.

Comment: Define "goes wrong", i.e. what's the result and what did you expect. Also, the expression contains several subexpressions. Which of these subexpressions does not have the value you would have expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes wrong because of this line, (and similar ones later)

```
swap(&middle, &arr[beg]);
```

`middle` is a separate variable, and when you swap using the above way, the actual element in the array (`array[middle]`) is not getting swapped (which you need).

---

You want to swap the elements in the index `beg` and `middle` of array. That can be achieved by doing

```
swap(&arr[middle], &arr[beg]);
```

Comment: One could also write: swap(arr + middle, arr +beg);

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll be careful about this!

Comment: @dongxingshi, Did you understand the problem?

Comment: @Haris Yes! I didn't swap the two numbers in the array but simply  one number in array.

Comment: @dongxingshi, Yes. Nice. Have fun coding. :)

Comment: @Haris I really appreciate your time and patience!

Comment: @dongxingshi, Thanks.. :)